# Texcount error File main.bbl not found in path (in overleaf)

Tags: bibtex, natbib, overleaf, latexmk, texcount

I am trying to add an automatic word count in my overleaf file using Texcount. I have followed the instructions on https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F exactly.

However my output is always (when using quickwordcount): x words (errors: 1)

The word count is actually correct, so my first question would be: Why doesn't the -q argument of texcount work? The errors should be hidden!

After further inspection, using a verbose output, I found out that the error actually is:
'!!! File main.bbl not found in path [./]. !!!'

This I also find really strange, because there is a main.bbl file in the directory.

What can I do to solve this?

My code:

file main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Bibliography management: BibTeX}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\detailtexcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -merge -sum -incbib #1.tex output.bbl > #1.wcdetail }%
  \verbatiminput{#1.wcdetail}%
}

\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-words.sum }%
  \input{#1-words.sum} words%
}
%TC:incbib


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\detailtexcount{main}

This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}%Used BibTeX style is unsrt
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
 
@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

Also added to the directory, a latexmkrc file with:

```
END { system('cp', 'output.bbl', 'main.bbl'); }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Could you please provide a compilable example?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have added an example. I used an example file to test if the problem also arises there (and it does). I think the main issue lies with using a bibliography and counting those words.

Comment: If I rename `main.tex` to `output.tex`, it works.  Overleaf's renaming of the main .tex file is a pain sometimes.  (Sorry, I don't know texcount enough to give you a better answer)

Comment: Thanks, this actually is a valid workaround! But should the latexmkrc file not take care of this? It may be that that configuration is no longer working.

Comment: The `END` hook seems to be executed at the _very_ end, just before `latexmk` quits (so long after `texcount` did its thing), so it's too late to rename anything

Comment: Hello, Tom from Support team here. It seems to work well for me, see my example project at https://www.overleaf.com/read/xhfvvvcxbxmb -- if you make a copy, you'll be able to comment out the two lines for the biliography and you'll see the count change accordingly. You'll see the error for missing main.bbl from texcount, but it shouldn't influence the numbers, which are correct.